# Uppercase Button in nativebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have a button with face book icon

```
<Button iconLeft block > <Icon name='logo-facebook' /> <Text>Login with facebook</Text> </Button>
```

with text "Login with facebook" But it displays "LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK" .I am tried with capitalize={false} but no hope.Is there any way?
NB version:2.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using `Native Base` Right ? maybe you can try this one.

you can change this code:

```
<Button iconLeft block > 
 <Icon name='logo-facebook' /> 
 <Text> {'Login with facebook'.toUpperCase()} </Text>
</Button>
```

to this :

```
<Button iconLeft block > 
 <Icon name='logo-facebook' /> 
 <Text uppercase={false}> {'Login with facebook'.toUpperCase()} </Text>
</Button>
```

just only using `uppercase={false}` in your `<text>` tag, hope it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
 text.capitalize-lowercase {text-transform: lowercase;}
text.capitalize-uppercase {text-transform: uppercase;}
```

```html
<button iconleft block> <icon name='logo-facebook' /> <text class="capitalize-uppercase">Login with facebook</text> </button>
 <br/> <br/>
<button iconleft block> <icon name='logo-facebook' /> <text class="capitalize-lowercase">Login with facebook</text> </button>
```

Comment: react native doesn't support text-transform

Answer (score 0):

I think text transform currently not support by react native style.So you can try something like this

```
<Button iconLeft block > 
 <Icon name='logo-facebook' /> 
 <Text> {'Login with facebook'.toUpperCase()} </Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: the original question is asking for lowercase text, not uppercase text.