# How to Display lowercase text in NativeBase Button

Tags: react-native, native-base

When I add a Text element in a Button according to the [examples](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#button-def-headref), the text shows up in uppercase. I need to display a button with lowercase text. I'm using native-base version 2.1.4. Any help with this will be most appreciated. As an example, if I include the code below, the button would say `SUBMIT` instead of `Submit`:

```
import { Button} from 'native-base';
<Button>
  <Text>Submit</Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about...all my buttons aren't defaulted to uppercase and none of those examples show it as all caps either...

Comment: @MattAft What version of native-base are you using? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048348/uppercase-button-in-nativebase), shows that I'm not the only one that's experienced this

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You try this its works for me

```
import { Button} from 'native-base';
 <Button>
   <Text uppercase={false}>Submit</Text>
</Button>
```

May be it can Help you !!!

Comment: Thanks! That works! I have to add though that it only worked after fiddling with my npm dependencies and dealing with multiple weird errors that I believe are due to version incompatibilities between native-base and react-native. I eventually ended up using [this compatibility table](http://rawgit.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-docs/v2.0/_book/docs/Compatibility.html) to figure out the right version. Now I'm using "native-base": "2.2.0" and "react-native": "0.45.1"